# Bad operand types for binary operator

Tags: java, generics

So I'm trying to make code generic and I'm coming across this problem, where I get an error that says bad operand types for binary operator.

Here is an example:

```
if(compare(data < root.data))
```

I get the error said above. Any hints on how to fix it?

I have this setup at the start of it:

```
class Node<T>
{
   T data;
   Node<T> left, right;

Node(T data)
    {
    this.data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if ( compare(data, root.data) < 0 )`?

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support operator overloading, The < operator is define for primitive data types like(int,double..).

It is not defined for non-primitive types or user define types.

You should use the Comparable interface instead of <.

Comment: This cleared things up alot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You call `data < root.data` but the operator `<` or other similar operators are **only defined** for **primitive datatypes** like `int`, `long`, `double`, `float`.

You can not call `<` on objects, in contrast to other languages which support **operator overloading**.

---

However you can let the objects implement `Comparable` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)) which provides a `compareTo` method that essentially does the same. You can then call it like this:

```
data.compareTo(root.data);
```

and it returns a **negative**-, **positive**- or **zero**-value, based on if the first argument is **less**, **greater** or **equal** the second argument.

So the equivalent to `data < root.data` would then be:

```
data.compareTo(root.data) < 0
```

As an example the class `String` has implemented `Comparable`, it returns the lexicographic order. `"A".compareTo("B")` therefore would be **negative**, meaning that `"A"` is lexicographical smaller than `"B"`.